# scroll Textview from out of collapse toolbar as title

Tags: android

I have one `CollapsingToolbar` and `NestedScrolView` under these contain of several `CardView` I want along with scroll up. Header `TextView` of one of `CardView` placed into toolbar. Thanks.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Anything you have tried? post that code.

Comment: in this view i have one collapsetoolbar and when these collapsed title appear with scroll in toolbar ( when these complitly collapsed) and it should to happen when head subject in content want scroll under toolbar

Comment: I used from observable ObservableScrollView and change alpha with change scroll